# PHP mail being flooded and queued

Tags: php, email, spam

I created a simple contact us form with php that resulted in sending an email to me using mail().

Someone used a program to spam it, and now I am receiving an email once a minute for the past two hours.  I have removed the mail() line in the php, but the emails keep coming.  I have submitted the contact form myself, and I have yet to receive my submission.

It appears that the emails are queued up or something.  Is there a way to clear the queue?  I am on shared hosting, so I do not have easy access to restart the server.

I have already updated the php with a fix to prevent spam based on IP.

Comment: restart your httpd

Comment: also, if your mail was exposed, nothing prevents them from continuing sending spam to that mail once they know it. you could block that email address to stop receiving them.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to restart your server, then take backup of all your necessary emails and delete your email account from your shared hosting and make it again after some time. All the queued up emails will then go back to the sender with the failure delivery. And your issue gets resolved after creating new same one.

But make sure to add some good `Captcha` script in your contact form to sort out the spam issue permanently.

Also make sure to secure your form to prevent `SQL injection` by adding PHP built-in functions like `htmlentities`, `stripslashes` and `mysql_real_escape_string` if adding in MySql database.